# Perspective 3D animation flickering in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, css-animations, css-transforms

I'm trying to create a 3D CSS effect of a door swinging opening and shutting. I have a CodePen with the animation work as I like it:

http://codepen.io/caleuanhopkins/pen/Dslpv

Here's the css:

```
.frame--realistic {
  perspective: 20em;
}

.door {
height: inherit;
background: darksalmon;
}

.frame {
margin: .5em auto;
border: solid 1em saddlebrown;
width: 500px;
height: 6.5em;
}

.door--open {
-webkit-transform-origin: 0 0 /*whatever y value you wish*/;
-moz-transform-origin: 0 0 /*whatever y value you wish*/;
-ms-transform-origin: 0 0 /*whatever y value you wish*/;
-o-transform-origin: 0 0 /*whatever y value you wish*/;
transform-origin: 0 0 /*whatever y value you wish*/;
-webkit-transform: rotateY(-45deg);
-moz-transform: rotateY(-45deg);
-ms-transform: rotateY(-45deg);
-o-transform: rotateY(-45deg);
transform: rotateY(-45deg);
}

@-webkit-keyframes doorani {
  from { 
-webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  to { 
-webkit-transform: rotateY(20deg);
  }
}


.frame:hover .door--ani {
-webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
-moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
-ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
-o-transform-origin: 0 0;
transform-origin: 0 0;
-moz-animation: doorani 1s 1 normal forwards;
-webkit-animation: doorani 1s 1 normal forwards;
-ms-animation: doorani 1s 1 normal forwards;
-o-animation: doorani 1s 1 normal forwards;
animation: doorani 1s 1 normal forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes doorout {
  from { 
-webkit-transform: rotateY(20deg);
  }
  to { 
-webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes doorani {
  from { 
-moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
-ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
-o-transform: rotateY(0deg);
transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  to { 
-moz-transform: rotateY(20deg);
-ms-transform: rotateY(20deg);
-o-transform: rotateY(20deg);
transform: rotateY(20deg);
  }
}

@keyframes doorout {
  from { 
-moz-transform: rotateY(20deg);
-ms-transform: rotateY(20deg);
-o-transform: rotateY(20deg);
transform: rotateY(20deg);
  }
  to { 
-moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
-ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
-o-transform: rotateY(0deg);
transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
}

.door--ani {
-webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
-moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
-ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
-o-transform-origin: 0 0;
transform-origin: 0 0;
-moz-animation: doorout 1s 1 normal forwards;
-webkit-animation: doorout 1s 1 normal forwards;
-ms-animation: doorout 1s 1 normal forwards;
-o-animation: doorout 1s 1 normal forwards;
animation: doorout 1s 1 normal forwards;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='frame frame--realistic'>
    <div class='door door--ani'> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, the main issue is when the door swings back after you have hovered over the door. There is a very slight flicker before the animation finishes. Does anyone have any idea why this is doing this and if there's anything I can change/add to fix this issue?

---

UPDATE: Code was originally not running for webkit browsers, I have now updated the code but the issues of the flickering still appears in Firefox.

Comment: I don't see a flicker on Chrome 37 for Windows. What browser are you on?

Comment: @ZachSaucier Try Firefox 32+

Comment: Yeah I saw the issue on Firefox originally